# Oracle SQL stored procedure with three select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, union

I working on converting an Oracle SQL query that is currently setup to run via JAVA into a stored procedure. Basically, there are three select statements from same table with a date range parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_users(startdate_in IN DATE,
                                      enddate_in   IN DATE)
IS
 BEGIN

    DELETE FROM temp_table;

    INSERT INTO temp_table (id, role, date_used, count_s)
      SELECT
        EMPLOYEE.CUSTOMERID                    AS user_id,
        'Customer'                             AS role_,
        to_char(EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON, 'MM-YYYY') AS req_month,
        count(EMPLOYEE.SUBJECT)                AS subj_count
      FROM RCUSER.EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE
      WHERE EMPLOYEE.STATEID NOT IN (4, 9, 16, 31, 36)
            AND (EMPLOYEE.AGENTID = 0)
            AND (EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON >= to_date(startdate_in, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
            AND (EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON < to_date(enddate_in, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
      GROUP BY CUSTOMERID, to_char(EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON, 'MM-YYYY')

      UNION

      SELECT
        EMPLOYEE.PERFORMERID                   AS user_id,
        'Performer'                            AS role_,
        to_char(EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON, 'MM-YYYY') AS req_month,
        count(EMPLOYEE.SUBJECT)                AS subj_count
      FROM RCUSER.EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE
      WHERE EMPLOYEE.PEID IN (1, 4, 6)
            AND EMPLOYEE.STATEID NOT IN (4, 9, 16, 31, 36)
            AND (EMPLOYEE.AGENTID = 0)
            AND (EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON >= to_date(startdate_in, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
            AND (EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON < to_date(enddate_in, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
      GROUP BY PERFORMERID, to_char(EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON, 'MM-YYYY')

      UNION

      SELECT
        employee.performerid                   AS user_id,
        'Approver'                             AS role_,
        to_char(EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON, 'MM-YYYY') AS req_month,
        count(EMPLOYEE.SUBJECT)                AS subj_count
      FROM RCUSER.EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE
      WHERE EMPLOYEE.PEID IN (2, 3)
            AND EMPLOYEE.STATEID NOT IN (4, 9, 16, 31, 36)
            AND (EMPLOYEE.AGENTID = 0)
            AND (EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON >= to_date(startdate_in, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
            AND (EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON < to_date(enddate_in, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
      GROUP BY PERFORMERID, to_char(EMPLOYEE.STARTEDON, 'MM-YYYY');

  END;
```

when running this nothing gets written into the `TEMP_TABLE`. But when I hard code the date range I get some data.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_PEOPLE(startdate_in IN DATE, enddate_in IN DATE)
IS

BEGIN
INSERT INTO temp_table
(ID, COL1, COL2, ROLE_,START_DATE,END_DATE)
VALUES
(select * from
(Select col1, col2, 'Customer' as Role_, col3, col3
where col1 in (1,2)
UNION
Select col1, col2, 'Authore' as Role_, col3, col3
where col1 in (3,4)
UNION
Select col1, col2,  'Buyer' as Role_,col3, col3
where col1 in (5,6))
where col3 between STARTDATE_IN and ENDDATE_IN;

END;
```

Of course there is a lot more you could do to write good code:

- add asserts that startdate_in and enddate_in are valid dates and are within expected values
- instead of a temp table return a sys refcursor with the results for processing in the applicaiton
- use a global temp table to cut down on undo logs

Comment: I used your suggestion, and it works if I have to hard code the date ranges. but when i pass the dates as variable it comes back empty. I used "date >= mystoreprocedure.startdate_in and date < "mystoreprocedure.enddate_in" under the where clause section.

Comment: you do not need to qualify parameters within a procedure.  STARTDATE_IN is sufficient.

Comment: then you would need to provide a sample of how you are calling the procedure and the output

Comment: i have updated my original SQL with the actual SQL that is being used. I run this stored procedure via Oracle SQL developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this more efficient with a single SQL statement of the form:

```
Select col1,
       col2,
       case
         when col1 in (1,2) then 'Customer'
         when col1 in (3,4) then 'Authore'
         when col1 in (5,6) then 'Buyer'
       end as Role_,
       col3(@startDate),
       col3(@endDate)
where col1 in (1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

If you need to write this to a temp table then just insert it ...

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure(start_date date, end_date date)
is
begin 
insert into temp_table (... column names ...)
Select col1,
       col2,
       case
         when col1 in (1,2) then 'Customer'
         when col1 in (3,4) then 'Authore'
         when col1 in (5,6) then 'Buyer'
       end as Role_,
       col3(my_procedure.start_date),
       col3(my_procedure.end_date)
where col1 in (1,2,3,4,5,6);
end;
/
```

Not sure what you mean by col3(@startDate) though ... maybe ...

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure(start_date date, end_date date)
is
begin 
insert into temp_table (... column names ...)
Select col1,
       col2,
       case
         when col1 in (1,2) then 'Customer'
         when col1 in (3,4) then 'Authore'
         when col1 in (5,6) then 'Buyer'
       end as Role_,
       my_procedure.start_date,
       my_procedure.end_date
where col1 in (1,2,3,4,5,6);
end;
/
```